# Can the Strunk and White requirement for reviewing be removed for users that already have the badge on one site?

Tags: feature-request, review, privileges, edit-badges

I wanted to start reviewing on other sites as well, especially Ask Ubuntu. So, I start by going to `/review`, and notice  that the count of the posts isn't getting smaller, although I'm 100% sure I've reviewed them.

To repeat: I review stuff, and **the posts don't go away**.

I look a little further and see that I need the Strunk and White badge to be able to track the review progress.

Say what? I've edited almost 6700 posts on Super User. I've reviewed 7600 posts there. It's not like I don't know what I'm doing.

**Can I please be trusted to review on other sites as well?**

The requirement for this badge does not make sense and is inconvenient at best. Getting Strunk and White is easily possible when you go through `/review`, but it's a hassle when the posts count never decreases and you always have to start on page 1.

Comment: As I understood it, the badge is only necessary for the display in the sidebar of the review panel, "you have voted up/down/edited/flagged/closed/deleted/reviewed x posts". That's 'tracking the review progress' (so you see when you get the reviewer badge).

Comment: I've reviewed all 31 first answers on AU today. They are still shown under "First Answers". That's the issue I'm talking about. Normally the posts would disappear after I've reviewed them.

Comment: I see that behaviour too on Code Review. However, as I understood it, that isn't the intended behaviour, and if memory serves, reviewed posts disappeared from the list on SO when I hadn't Strunk&White there yet. So if I'm right, it's a bug.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Well, I'm gonna wait for @waffles to tell us :)

Comment: @DanielFischer: You do definitely have to have the badge in order for your "reviews" to count.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few privileges that I'd prefer to carry over network-wide (eg vote counts). This isn't one of them.

Each site has different post quality rules, and edits must adhere to those as well. This requires a bit more participation.

Also, as a newbie to the site, you may not know of some edits that ought to be made. For example, on Mathematics.SE, Physics.SE, Chemistry.SE, etc a seasoned editor will know that posts with plaintext math (usually) are to be LaTeX-ified . There probably are other such guidelines elsewhere. So, if a new user edits/comments in the review queue, it shouldn't disappear from the queue--there may be other things to look for.

*Another* concern is how easy it is to get 2k and the badges on some sites. Especially SO (where nobody will notice your edits as the front page is anyway flooded). Such users may not really know what edits are for, and we don't want them to remove questions from scrutiny on other sites via the review section.

So basically, in my opinion, it is preferable to keep such privileges separate for each site.

---

**Edit:** OK, now I see what you mean--you mainly want it removed from your *own* queue.

As per the above half of this post, I do not advocate giving the "remove from the `/review` queue for everyone". I don't support any non-read-only privileges copying over sites (except the ones that already do like commenting). Even if the privilege is rather minor like this one (my kook opinion, I guess :P)

But, I think that this would be nice--a checkbox in `/review` marked "hide posts which I have already reviewed", and that hides such posts regardless of your badges. This may be a pain to implement, though.

Comment: These are not real arguments against that. *> So, if a new user edits/comments in the review queue, it shouldn't disappear from the queue--there may be other things to look for.* — just one user reviewing a post does not remove it from the queue. If I make edits that are considered *too minor*, they'd be rejected anyway. This is simply a matter of enabling users to review properly. Answers that are not answers still remain the same, regardless of the site. Spelling mistakes and wrong formatting are everywhere to be found.

Comment: @slhck: _just one user reviewing a post does not remove it from the queue_ -- right, forgot about that. Also about the fact that you still need to get 2k on the site to be able to bypass approval (for some reason I thought you had edit privileges on the site). Still, I'm against the idea of any non-read-only privileges carrying over sites. The rep you get is how much the community _of a site_ trusts you to blow up their posts. I do see that this is a rather minor privilege here (not much destructive capabilities), but I stand by my "no". Rather shakily, though. :\

Comment: Anyway, I'll clarify it a bit.

Comment: It should be standard behavior to just remove everything I've reviewed from my own queue. **Why do I need to see it again?** Why do I need to click through everything again? There is **no** reasonable argument for that. It's almost like deliberately hindering people from reviewing properly. There's no "working" through the queue if every post just reappears.

Comment: @slhck: I completely agree with that :) I suggested a checkbox, but it can be done by default as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you give the process a week or so, your edits will get you the badge anyways, and you won't have the problem.

I don't really see cross-site badges as a solution, despite the fact that Stack Overflow is not a role-playing game - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not/128563#128563. Your badges are a sign of accomplishment, and if you didn't earn them on that site, then you don't get them there.

Comment: I never said I wanted to get the same badge again — just that the requirement should be removed accordingly.